# how to map fields in feeds module with csv that has no headers?

Tags: feeds

Can feeds module still know how to map the fields correctly even if there are no headers in a .csv file. I am trying to migrate sample data from database which i exported to a .csv file through phpmyadmin. i am testing the feeds module if it can handle large file migrate.

if the answer is no, can i manually input the headers in the excel files? or it has to be exported again with headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module support CSV files without column headers.  On admin/structure/feeds/foo_importer/settings/FeedsCSVParser, you just need to select "No Headers".  Then on admin/structure/feeds/foo_importer/mapping, you use the column numbers for the source.

Be careful when entering the Name of source field. Your first column is named '0', the second '1' and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Triskelion for the reminder about the column numbers.

Comment: So the source field i am suppose to enter is the numbers? not the actual name of the source field? im talking about the mapping page in feeds.

Comment: @Belmark  Yes, use the column number. Column A in the XLS is 0, B is 1, C is 2, etc.

Comment: I get the error: *You must select a mapping source.* when I enter **0** as a source column.

Comment: @Batandwa I think the problem is that you need to select "No Headers", but I would need to remember which site I have, as all of my recent sites have used headers.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I applied [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1984962#comment-7388980) and it worked.